# Convert in a Sturm-Liouville form $y''+R(x)y'+(Q(x)+\lambda p(x))y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

Convert in a Sturm-Liouville form $$y''+R(x)y'+(Q(x)+\lambda P(x))y=0\tag1$$

**My attempt:**

The form of Sturm-Liouville is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}[r(x) \frac{dy}{dx}]+(q(x)+\lambda p(x))y=0\tag2$$

For obtain this, we need multiply for $\mu(x)$ the ODE $(1)$. This result in:

$$\mu y''+\mu R(x)y'+(\mu Q(x)+\lambda \mu P(x))y=0 \tag3$$

I need rewrite the first term of $(3)$.

Here, i'm stuck. I don't have a clear idea of how rewrite and then proceed for solve the exercise.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

If we expand out equation $(2)$, we get
$$ r(x) y'' + r'(x) y' + (q(x) + \lambda p(x)) y = 0 \ \ \ \ \ (2a).$$

So the objective is to choose the functions $\mu(x)$, $r(x)$, $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ so that your equation $(3)$ matches my equation $(2a)$.

Comparing the individual terms, the requirement is that
$$ \mu(x) = r(x), \ \ \ \ \ \mu(x)R(x) = r'(x), \ \ \ \ \  \mu(x)Q(x) = q(x), \ \ \ \ \ \mu(x)P(x) = p(x).$$
The first of these equations is straightforward: it tells us that $\mu(x)$ and $r(x)$ must be the *same function.*

Given that $\mu(x) = r(x)$, the second equation says that
$$ \mu(x) R(x) = \mu'(x),$$
and this is satisfied by

$$ \mu(x) = \exp \left(\int dx \ R(x) \right).$$

I'll leave you to figure out what $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ and finish off.

Comment: Thanks, i will go to expand your idea right now!

Comment: Expanding your idea i have $q(x)=(\exp{\int R(x)dx})Q(x)$ and $p(x)=(\exp{\int R(x)dx})P(x)$ is correct?

Comment: @Bvss12 looks good to me!

Comment: Then, can i conclude... if $\mu(x) = r(x)= \exp \left(\int dx \ R(x) \right).$ and $q(x)=(\exp{\int R(x)dx})Q(x)$, and $p(x)=(\exp{\int R(x)dx})P(x)$ then the equation 1 is a Sturm-Liouville equation. is correct? Thanks for all help (:

Comment: I believe so, yes.